# "Let m $\in N$ s.t $m = 2s$, where s is an odd integer. Prove that there do not exist positive integers x and y such that $x^{2} − y^{2} = m$."

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

sometimes the answers in my book differ from my solution and I become paranoid about it, can someone please varify if this is correct.Also offtopic, no need to answer, are verification questions allowed(welcomed) here?

Question again:
"Let m $\in N$ s.t $m = 2s$, where s is an odd integer. Prove that there do not exist positive integers x and y such that $x^{2} − y^{2} = m$."

The following two lemmas are given:
Lemma 1: $x^{2}$ and $x$ have the same parity.
Lemma 2: $a + b$ and $a - b$ are only even when $a$ and $b$ have the same parity.

Proof by contradiction.
We have the following equation.
$$x^{2} − y^{2} = 2s$$
which means that $x^{2} − y^{2}$ is even. By lemma 2 both $x^{2}$ and $y^{2}$ have the same parity which by lemma 1 means that $x$ and $y$ have the same parity. We have two cases, $x$ and $y$ are both even or are both odd.

Case 1 :
Asume that $x$ and $y$ are both even.
$$x^{2} − y^{2} = (2a)^{2} - (2b)^{2} = 4a^{2} - 4b^{2} = 4(a^{2} - b^{2})$$
$$ 4(a^{2} - b^{2}) = 2s $$
$$ 2(a^{2} - b^{2}) = s $$
where $a,b \in Z$. As we see s is even which is a contradiction.

Case 2 :
Asume that $x$ and $y$ are both odd.
$$x^{2} − y^{2} = (2a+1)^{2} - (2b+1)^{2} = 4a^{2}+4a+1-4b^{2}-4b-1 = 4(a^{2} - b^{2} + a - b)$$
$$ 4(a^{2} - b^{2} + a - b) = 2s $$
$$ 2(a^{2} - b^{2} + a - b) = s $$
where $a,b \in Z$. As we see s is even which again is a contradiction.
$\blacksquare$

Edit: removed WLOG and wrote the second case.

Comment: Proof verification questions are fine on MSE.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ have the same parity and so $4\mid x^2-y^2$ is always correct, but $4\not\mid 2s$. This completes the proof.

Comment: You can't assume without loss of generality they are both even.  But you can do the case where they are both odd as a separate case.

Comment: Not the must direct but once you establish you have $x,y$ the same parity not that $x^2 -y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$ and $x+y$ and $x-y$ are both even.

Comment: @fleablood I think, OP needs to understand that what is exactly WLOG. Because, in this case WLOG is not relevant. If you explain in your answer, I will definitely vote.

Comment: I don't think I'll answer because....I don't like to tell posters "don't do it your way; do it mine" and because the OP has basically gotten it except for assuming both are even is wolog.  Wolog is when the difference in both cases a easily seen to be essentially the same (maybe it's relabeling; maybe it reduces) but odds and evens are not at all essentially the same.  But the OP has correctly done the odd case.  So really, No answer is nesc.  In fact... If I were mean I could be justified in downvoting *any* answer as no answer is needed. (*I've* certainly been downvoted enough for that.)

Comment: With the edit this post is just fine and correct.

Comment: +1 to your question for nice work shown.

Comment: @fleablood just expressing my doubt.. what if we try to prove this using the difference of squares? For instance, assume $x = y + y'$ and hence $x^2 - y^2 = 2xy' + (y')^2$...